# Is it possible in Libgdx that two bodies of type StaticBody can collide? (Box2D)

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, box2d

I am new using the library and incorporating box2d, I have run into a problem and that is that I have created 2 protagonists of which both are dynamic and I would like to know if there is any way or any function to indicate that they can collide with each other and I don't know cross over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ContactListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ContactListener.html), to let the Box2D world inform you, about every contact of objects. Therefore your protagonist's classes need to implement the `ContactListener` interface and be registered in the Box2D world (using the [setContactListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World.html#setContactListener-com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ContactListener-) method).

Now if any contact happens, the [beginContact](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ContactListener.html#beginContact-com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact-) method of your protagonist's class will be called.

But this will happen for every contact. Not only the contacts between your protagonists, so you'll have to filter. This is usually done, by checking the [Fixtures](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture.html) of a [Contact](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Contact.html) (that is passed to your `beginContact` method). Using the `Fixtures` you can get the colliding `Body` and its user data, which you can set to the protagonist to identify him.

For further information have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-box2d-contact-listener/) or the [libGDX documentation on Box2D](https://libgdx.com/wiki/extensions/physics/box2d)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I read the documentation, I managed to do it in another way, I don't know if it's the best way but it works quite well.
I put the shape.setAsBox inside b2body.createFixture(shape,0);